# fir1 in octave with boxcar

Tags: function, matlab, filter, octave

I have to make filter, this is my code:

```
octave:1> x=randn(500);
octave:2> b=fir1(50,0.2,'stop',boxcar(51));
error: `boxcar' undefined near line 2 column 22
error: evaluating argument list element number 4
```

What is problem here?

Also Low-pass filter is 'low' or 'stop' in Octave?

@edit
New error:

```
octave:2> b=fir1(50,0.2,'stop');
error: `fir1' undefined near line 2 column 3
```

is it possible I don't have something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [man page](http://octave.sourceforge.net/signal/function/fir1.html):

```
usage: b = fir1(n, w [, type] [, window] [, noscale])
```

You probably want e.g.:

```
b=fir1(50, [0.1 0.2], 'stop');
```

Comment: I am using ubuntu, octave version 3.6.2

Comment: See updated answer above - see also linked man page for `fir1`.

Comment: OK - it sounds like you don't even have fir1 installed. You need to go to http://octave.sourceforge.net/packages.php and install the relevant package, signal: http://octave.sourceforge.net/signal/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to load the package (see the [Octave FAQ](http://wiki.octave.org/FAQ#I_have_installed_a_package_but_still_get_a_.22foo_undefined.22_error)). Run `pkg list` to confirm the package is installed and whether it is loaded. It will display a table of all installed packages with an asterisk in front of the packages that are loaded. You won't be able to use packages that are not loaded. See the following Octave session.

```
octave> partcnt (7)   # does not work because function is not in search path
error: `partcnt' undefined near line 9 column 1
octave> pkg list      # show list of packages
Package Name   | Version | Installation directory
---------------+---------+-----------------------
      control  |   2.4.1 | /home/carandraug/octave/control-2.4.1
      general  |   1.3.2 | /home/carandraug/octave/general-1.3.2
generate_html  |   0.1.5 | /home/carandraug/octave/generate_html-0.1.5
        image  |   2.1.0 | /home/carandraug/octave/image-2.1.0
miscellaneous  |   1.2.0 | /home/carandraug/octave/miscellaneous-1.2.0
        optim  |   1.2.2 | /home/carandraug/octave/optim-1.2.2
       signal  |   1.2.0 | /home/carandraug/octave/signal-1.2.0
      specfun  |   1.1.0 | /home/carandraug/octave/specfun-1.1.0
       struct  |  1.0.10 | /home/carandraug/octave/struct-1.0.10

octave> pkg load miscellaneous  # load package
octave> partcnt (7)             # it works now
ans =  15
octave> pkg list                # confirm that package is loaded (* in front of the name)
Package Name   | Version | Installation directory
---------------+---------+-----------------------
      control  |   2.4.1 | /home/carandraug/octave/control-2.4.1
      general *|   1.3.2 | /home/carandraug/octave/general-1.3.2
generate_html  |   0.1.5 | /home/carandraug/octave/generate_html-0.1.5
        image  |   2.1.0 | /home/carandraug/octave/image-2.1.0
miscellaneous *|   1.2.0 | /home/carandraug/octave/miscellaneous-1.2.0
        optim  |   1.2.2 | /home/carandraug/octave/optim-1.2.2
       signal  |   1.2.0 | /home/carandraug/octave/signal-1.2.0
      specfun  |   1.1.0 | /home/carandraug/octave/specfun-1.1.0
       struct  |  1.0.10 | /home/carandraug/octave/struct-1.0.10

octave> pkg unload all    # unload the package
octave> partcnt (7)       # no longer works because it was removed from path
error: `partcnt' undefined near line 15 column 1
octave> pkg list
Package Name   | Version | Installation directory
---------------+---------+-----------------------
      control  |   2.4.1 | /home/carandraug/octave/control-2.4.1
      general  |   1.3.2 | /home/carandraug/octave/general-1.3.2
generate_html  |   0.1.5 | /home/carandraug/octave/generate_html-0.1.5
        image  |   2.1.0 | /home/carandraug/octave/image-2.1.0
miscellaneous  |   1.2.0 | /home/carandraug/octave/miscellaneous-1.2.0
        optim  |   1.2.2 | /home/carandraug/octave/optim-1.2.2
       signal  |   1.2.0 | /home/carandraug/octave/signal-1.2.0
      specfun  |   1.1.0 | /home/carandraug/octave/specfun-1.1.0
       struct  |  1.0.10 | /home/carandraug/octave/struct-1.0.10
```

The reason why the general package is loaded automatically when you load `miscellaneous`, is because `general` is a dependency of `miscellaneous`.